# How do I reinstall a globally installed dotnet package

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

I have a nuget package that I installed the following way:

```
dotnet new --install Umbraco.Templates::10.2.0
```

Now, I've run into some issues with this package, and the only solution that I have found that I have not tried yet, is to remove and install the package again.

So I google how to do that. But the only things I can find is commands made for removing the package for a specific project. Can I somehow globally remove the package and then install it again the same way as I did before?

Comment: That's a template, not a package

Comment: What are the issues? A template is nothing more than a set of folders to create into a target output folder, plus some value substitutions. It has little effect on the NuGet packages actually used by your projects. Upgrading or reinstalling it won't affect any existing projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a template, not a global package. The docs explain [how custom templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) work, how to create your own, install or uninstall a template using switches on the `dotnet new` command.

What this particular page is missing is [how to check and apply template updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-update). This is done with the `--update-check` and `--update-apply` switches.

You can check if there are any template updates with :

```
dotnet new --update-check
```

You can apply new updates with

```
dotnet new --update-apply
```

You don't have to use `--update-check` before `--update-apply`.

You can use `dotnet new --help` to list all options of the `dotnet new` command

**Reinstalling**

Using `dotnet new --install` *should* remove the existing version and reinstall it. In .NET 7 this becomes `dotnet new install` :

```
dotnet new --install  Umbraco.Templates
```

If that doesn't work, the template can be uninstalled with `uninstall` and installed again :

```
dotnet new --uninstall  Umbraco.Templates
dotnet new --install  Umbraco.Templates
```

**.NET 7**

Starting with .NET 7 `update` becomes a subcommand.

To check *and* apply, use `dotnet new update`. That's what developers want most of the time.

To check for new versions, use add the `--check-only` or `--dry-run` switch :

```
dotnet new update --check-only
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I for sure had a little confusion about the terminology. The issue though is not that I want to update, but rather I want to reinstall. The template is currently completely up to date

Comment: @gongdongflong running `dotnet new --install  Umbraco.Templates` should remove the existing version and reinstall it. If that doesn't work, use `dotnet new --uninstall` to manually remove it and `dotnet new --install` again to install it. That's just the template though. It won't change the actual NuGet packages used by the generated projects.